# Selective 404 response in AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

#### Question

I would like to implement these simple rules

- if the path starts with `/assets/` and the file is really missing, return HTTP error 404
- if the path is anything else, serve the content of `index.html` without redirecting.

#### My current investigation

I have a static website in AWS S3 bucket configured as an origin for CloudFront. The website is a SPA and I would like nice URL paths to be all routed to the app.

- I can configure `index.html` to be served instead of all errors in CloudFront or in S3 Static Website Hosting. It works for app routes but all missing assets are also served as index.html with code 200.
- I can't find any configuration to make these rules more complex in CloudFront.
- There is some advanced configuration in AWS S3 Static Website Hosting - Redirection rules - but these rules really perform just HTTP redirection (`Location` header), not a content replacement. Additionally, these rules can't describe the exception - for missing `/assets/` just do nothing special and return an error - is impossible to define.
- I can see some "Function associations" in CloudFront Behavior definition, but I don't know how to use them and it seems to me as overkill for this simple task. But maybe it is the only solution. (I know AWS Lambda, but I don't know what to write as a code in this particular case and where to put them in the pipeline).